# Number format exception when importing comma separated numbers from txt file

Tags: java

I am trying to input a file with integer coma separated values from 1 to 100. Which looks like this : `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100`

I want this values to be stored in `List<Integer>`. I wrote a constructor which looks like this :

```
private String bName;
private List<Integer> X = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private WhiteBags W;


Bags(File fil,String c, String a) throws WrongPath, NegativeInteger{
    this.bName = c;
    this.W = new WhiteBags(a);
    FileReader inputFil;
    BufferedReader in;
    try {
        inputFil = new FileReader(fil);
        in = new BufferedReader(inputFil);

        String s = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(s);

        for(String n:s.split(", ")){
            X.add(Integer.parseInt(n));
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
        throw new WrongPath("File doesn't exists");
    }

}
```

But when I try to compile it returns an Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at Bags.<init>(Bags.java:27)
    at test.main(test.java:5)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did it print out the ´readLine()´ from your ´BufferedReader´ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
s.split(", ")
```

to

```
s.split(",")
```

Your current code is looking for a comma followed by a space but the input doesn't have spaces